# I want to make my file on google drive public

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I am trying to upload and then share a file on google drive in android. I am able to get its  file id and resource id. Now I want to make it public so that users with link can access it . How do I do it programmatically ?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Permissions.create](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/permissions/create) and set the type of the file to "anyone".
     Here's a code snippet from the [Manage Sharing in Drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-sharing) guide:

```
    String fileId = "1sTWaJ_j7PkjzaBWtNc3IzovK5hQf21FbOw9yLeeLPNQ";
JsonBatchCallback<Permission> callback = new JsonBatchCallback<Permission>() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(GoogleJsonError e,
                          HttpHeaders responseHeaders)
            throws IOException {
        // Handle error
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Permission permission,
                          HttpHeaders responseHeaders)
            throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Permission ID: " + permission.getId());
    }
};
BatchRequest batch = driveService.batch();
Permission userPermission = new Permission()
        .setType("user")
        .setRole("writer")
        .setEmailAddress("user@example.com");
driveService.permissions().create(fileId, userPermission)
        .setFields("id")
        .queue(batch, callback);

Permission domainPermission = new Permission()
        .setType("domain")
        .setRole("reader")
        .setDomain("example.com");
driveService.permissions().create(fileId, domainPermission)
        .setFields("id")
        .queue(batch, callback);

batch.execute();
```

Comment: I already tried doing so. i get this error saying:    Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.api.client.googleapis.batch.BatchRequest com.google.api.services.drive.Drive.batch()' on a null object reference.  What should I do?

Comment: Error 404, I think google drive not except batch request now a days.